# Revit API SharpDeveloper

Tags: api, revit, sharpdevelop

When Im writing a plugin in Visual studio, its very nice to attach the plug in to Revit and get feedback at the time my plug in fails.  I can inspect all the variables etc.. and get the error is relatively informative.

When Im writing a macro with sharp develop - the error message thrown in Revit is relatively vague.  I know I can step through a macro - but this can be cumbersome when going through a foreach loop of all the views.  Is there any way to get back into sharp development at the point of failure so I can inspect whats going on with the code?

Answer (score 0):

Can't you set a conditional breakpoint in SharpDevelop, like in the Visual Studio debugger? Then you could loop through hundreds of views and break at one specific one by matching the name or element id or some other specific identifier...